# How to make page turning effect in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, animation, flutter-animation

I want to create animation like turning page which is more likely a stiffened card with curvature at the centre while turning the page in flutter but I could only make it a turn animation like a flat card like below.

[image]

But I need to make some curvature at center to make it feel like turning a long photo album how can I make the curvature there.

What I have tried is

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flip Animation Example'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _showFrontSide;
  bool _flipXAxis;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _showFrontSide = true;
    _flipXAxis = true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(this.widget.title),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: RotatedBox(
              child: Icon(Icons.flip),
              quarterTurns: _flipXAxis ? 0 : 1,
            ),
            onPressed: _changeRotationAxis,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: DefaultTextStyle(
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size.square(200.0)),
            child: _buildFlipAnimation(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _changeRotationAxis() {
    setState(() {
      _flipXAxis = !_flipXAxis;
    });
  }

  void _switchCard() {
    setState(() {
      _showFrontSide = !_showFrontSide;
    });
  }

  Widget _buildFlipAnimation() {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _switchCard,
      child: AnimatedSwitcher(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        transitionBuilder: __transitionBuilder,
        layoutBuilder: (widget, list) => Stack(children: [widget, ...list]),
        child: _showFrontSide ? _buildFront() : _buildRear(),
        switchInCurve: Curves.easeInBack,
        switchOutCurve: Curves.easeInBack.flipped,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget __transitionBuilder(Widget widget, Animation<double> animation) {
    final rotateAnim = Tween(begin: pi, end: 0.0).animate(animation);
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: rotateAnim,
      child: widget,
      builder: (context, widget) {
        final isUnder = (ValueKey(_showFrontSide) != widget.key);
        var tilt = ((animation.value - 0.5).abs() - 0.5) * 0.003;
        tilt *= isUnder ? -1.0 : 1.0;
        final value = isUnder ? min(rotateAnim.value, pi / 2) : rotateAnim.value;
        return Transform(
          transform: _flipXAxis
              ? (Matrix4.rotationY(value)..setEntry(3, 0, tilt))
              : (Matrix4.rotationX(value)..setEntry(3, 1, tilt)),
          child: widget,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFront() {
    return __buildLayout(
      key: ValueKey(true),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      faceName: "Front",
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: ColorFiltered(
          colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.white, BlendMode.srcATop),
          child: FlutterLogo(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRear() {
    return __buildLayout(
      key: ValueKey(false),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade700,
      faceName: "Rear",
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: ColorFiltered(
          colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.white, BlendMode.srcATop),
          child: Center(child: Text("Flutter", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0))),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget __buildLayout({Key key, Widget child, String faceName, Color backgroundColor}) {
    return Container(
      key: key,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        color: backgroundColor,
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(faceName.substring(0, 1), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 80.0)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

https://pub.dev/packages/page_turn
This is an old one from flutter community
Or

https://pub.dev/packages/better_page_turn
This is new one from the same developer of better player

Comment: I need to animation to have curvature but in better_page_turn there is no curvature in the paper see it in [here](https://github.com/WangYng/better_page_turn)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/1ac2e44f68c9edd9c830f8d935b5866d. You can use this. But you may have to edit codes to make it null safe.

Comment: Yeah I have also tried it earlier but I couldn’t make a front and back pages. Is there something else better suits my needs